# javascript setCustomValidity doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript,I wanna check if the passwords typing two times are matched using Javascript. But it seems doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkpasswd(){
    var p1 = getElementById("password1");
    var p2 = getElementById("password2");
    if( p1.value != p2.value){
        p2.setCustomValidity("passwd don't match");
    }else{
        p2.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
    passwd:<input type="password" name="password1" id="password1">
    confirm passwd:<input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" onchange="checkpasswd()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use the [development console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console), these issues are relatively easy to debug.

Answer (score 4):

Use **document.getElementById()** and use the right **id**:

```
function checkpasswd(){
    var p1 = document.getElementById("password1");
    var p2 = document.getElementById("password2");
    if( p1.value != p2.value){
        p2.setCustomValidity("passwd don't match");
    }else{
        p2.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}
```

Comment: The id is typo,I think I miss use the onchange event

Answer (score 0):

i have edited your code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkpasswd(){
    var p1 = document.getElementById("password1");
    var p2 = document.getElementById("password2");
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    if( p1.value != p2.value){
        result.innerHTML = "passwd don't match";
        p2.setCustomValidity("passwd don't match");
    }else{
        result.innerHTML = "passwd  match";
        p2.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
    passwd:<input type="password" name="password1" id="password1">
    confirm passwd:<input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" onkeyup="checkpasswd()">
    </form>

    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does the setCustomValidity function do? seem useless,could you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

The id name u are using to find an element is misspelled. You need to mention the correct ID to get the element.

You forgot to use document object, and directly trying to access getElementById.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkpasswd(){
    var p1 = document.getElementById("password1");
    var p2 = document.getElementById("password2");
    if( p1.value !== p2.value){
        p2.setCustomValidity("passwd don't match");
    }else{
        p2.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
    passwd:<input type="password" name="password1" id="password1">
    confirm passwd:<input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" onchange="checkpasswd()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```